# Disk [grants.jpg] does not have a configured driver. laravel 8

Tags: laravel, e-commerce

Am trying to save different image sizes with its original filename but its refusing and it keeps giving me the above error
**Below is my code**

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image_tmp = $request->file('image');
            if ($image_tmp->isValid()) {
                    $filename = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
                    $large_image_path = $request->image->store('images/backend_img/products/large', $filename);
                    $medium_image_path = $request->image->store('images/backend_img/products/medium', $filename);
                    $small_image_path = $request->image->store('images/backend_img/products/small', $filename);
                    //Resize Images
                    Image::make($image_tmp)->save($large_image_path);
                    Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(600,600)->save($medium_image_path);
                    Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(300,300)->save($small_image_path);
                     //store image name in products table
                    $product->image = $filename;
                 }
        }
```

Below is the filesystems.php code

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
    ],

],
```

Comment: Clearly you have a problem in the config file: `filesystems.php`. It seems to be missing the key `driver`. How about you update your post with that file?

Comment: Brother have u solved the issue ?